# Terminology: Is tab a non-breaking space?

Tags: javascript, whitespace, terminology

AFAIK, nbsp (non-breaking space) is this: . But tab (`\t`) is also a non-breaking space right? I mean it doesn't create a new line.

If everything above is correct, then how would you call a variable that can contain either  or  `\t` ? Something ugly like `tabOrNbsp`?

I am asking because currently in my code a variable called `nbsp` is used for that purpose, but the ambiguity makes me sick. Or is it correct as it is now?

P.S. This question is so dumb, but don't hate, now I see how dumb it was. In the end the commenters and the answerer really helped to sort things out!

Comment: Why do you think words with a tab within won’t break?

Comment: @insertusernamehere Hi, because it doesn't break, i.e. create new line, I guess. Breaking is creating a new line, if I am not wrong.

Comment: No, that is not want non-breaking means, it means it won't split to a new line when it overflows.

Comment: _"In word processing and digital typesetting, a non-breaking space (" "), also called no-break space, non-breakable space (NBSP), hard space, or fixed space, is a space character that prevents an automatic line break at its position. In some formats, including HTML, it also prevents consecutive whitespace characters from collapsing into a single space. In HTML, the common non-breaking space, which is the same width as the ordinary space character, is encoded as `&nbsp;` or `&#160;`. In Unicode, it is encoded as `U+00A0`._" (Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space))

Comment: @Titus OMG, I think I've messed everything up. Your comment makes it clear for me!

Comment: @Andreas I've read it but for some reason your comment made it clearer maybe in the context of the other comments

Comment: No, there are only 4 [non-breaking space characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Width_variation). The tabulator character is not among them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the term "[non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)".

Normally, although a space or tab character doesn't *require* a line break, it *allows* line-wrapping. So if a paragraph goes on long enough, it will eventually spread across multiple lines, even if you use lots of spaces and tabs.

A "non-breaking space" is a space that does *not* allow line-wrapping; if two words have a non-breaking space between them, then those two words will always end up on the same line, even if they're at the end of a line and you would otherwise expect line-wrapping between them. In Unicode, non-breaking space is coded as a specific character, U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE, and in HTML, you can use the entity reference `&nbsp;` to conveniently embed this character. This character is different from the normal space character , which in Unicode is coded as U+0020 SPACE.

If I've correctly understood the idea that you have in mind, the closest term is probably "[linear white space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21072713/978917)" (LWS or LWSP), which means a sequence of space or tab characters (the idea being that these are whitespace characters "within a line", not forcing a line break).

Comment: Thank you very much for this clarification. Your answer and the comments helped me, and I guess I'll use the term `horizontal whitespace`. Do you think it's correct for every whitespace that doesn't create a new line?

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev: "Horizontal whitespace" sounds good to me!

Comment: Great! Thanks, I'll use it then. BTW "Linear white space" confused me with this: "Linear white space is: any number of spaces or horizontal tabs, and also **newline** (CRLF) if...", otherwise I'd use it instead.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev: That "newline (CRLF)" is because in HTTP 1.x, a newline in HTTP headers is ignored if it's followed by a space or tab. So it's part of what's *semantically* just linear whitespace.